# Print json response from API in R

Tags: json, r, api, httr

I have been using `httr` library in `R` and the function `GET`. I encoded this line:

```
GET(url,add_headers("user" = "password"))
```

And this is the response:

```
Response [url]
  Date: 2015-10-28 08:38
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
  Size: 10.6 kB
```

I want to know how can I print the json response of this API.

Comment: content(GET(url,add_headers("user" = "password"))) will show you whats in the response. Your header looks a bit strange, it 'normaly'
looks like "user" = username, "password" = password but totally depends on the API.

Comment: I used `content` function and set response as `parse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used function `content` to turn my result into `json` as seen below:

```
data_get<- GET(url,add_headers("user" = "password"))

get2json<- content(data_get, as = "parsed")

parse2json<- (toJSON(get2json))
```

Comment: or just `content(data_get, as = "text")`

Comment: It could be `as="text"` but to transfer the data back to JSON I need to used `"parse"`

Comment: no, no you don't. the `text` will be actual JSON strings

Comment: I tested using `text` and add the json here http://jsoneditoronline.org/ but it just won't read it. Making it `as ='parse'` and then converting it to JSON is the only thing it read.